# Another change src image with jquery and replace ..?

Tags: jquery, replace

i need to change the src of div class big when click on a preview class..

```
<div class="big"> <img src="image_big_1.jpg"> </div>
<div class="preview"> <img src="image_preview_2.jpg"> </div>
<div class="preview"> <img src="image_preview_3.jpg"> </div>
```

Exact result expected in this case :

you click on

```
<div class="preview"> <img src="image_preview_3.jpg"> </div>
```

and

```
<div class="big">
```

src change like this :

```
<div class="big"> <img src="image_big_3.jpg"> </div>
```

Someone help me with this ,guess its not so far:

```
$('.big img').attr('src', $('.preview    img').attr('src').replace(?) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.preview img').click(function(){
      var preview = $(this).attr('src');
      preview = preview.replace('preview','big');
      $('.big img').attr('src',preview);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $bimg = $('.big img');
    $('.preview').click(function(){
        var $img = $(this).find('img');
        $bimg.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace('preview', 'big');
    })
})
```